# Importing java file to jsp - cannot be resolved to a type error

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

So, after searching the web for a few hours, I decided to post my question here:

I'm writing a web project , running it on tomcat Apache through Xampp (a program that runs servers).

I wrote a java file called "MyConnection" that establishes a connection to a mysql database and does all kinds of other things.The file is in package java_files.

I need to import said file to a jsp file called "login" so that I can send user and password to the database to check if they are correct.

I tried to import the java file using all kinds of options -

```
<%@ page import="java_files.MyConnection"%>
```

and then:

```
<%
MyConnection myCon = new MyConnection();

%>
```

but it just gives me a "could not resolve to a type" error

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [14] in the generated java file: [C:\xampp\tomcat\work\Catalina\localhost\targil1_facebook\org\apache\jsp\WebContent\login_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. java_files.MyConnection resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: 18 in the jsp file: /WebContent/login.jsp
MyConnection cannot be resolved to a type
15: 
16: 
17: <%
18: MyConnection myCon = new MyConnection();
19: 
20: %>
21:
```

I could not find any working solution. I tried:

1.cleaning the project

2.set output build folder to Web-Inf (there is a MyContent.class file in the folder under "java_file" folder which cannot be seen from the eclipse project explorer but I can see it if I open it in a folder)

3.running the project with Apache tomcat in eclipse

4.various options of import strings (with package name/ without , * instead of class name and so on)

and I cannot make it work!

Please, help me find a solution!!!
Thank you!

Comment: What is inside `MyConnection` ?

Comment: MyConnection is a java file that contains code that connects with the jdbc driver to the mysql database.

Comment: Does it contain some package reference?

Comment: It imports java.sql.* and has a "package java_files;" at the top to indicate that it resides in the java_files package. I tried importing the java.sql.* into the jsp file as well but it still displays the same error

Comment: I think you should remove the `package java_files` but not the import, just change the path for import

Comment: You mean <%@ page import="MyConnection"%> ? it says "The import MyConnection cannot be resolved" so it can't find it

Comment: No, inside your java file

Comment: If I remove the package declaration it gives me an error

Comment: Where is Myconnection class? is it in the same project with jsp or is it in another project? if it is in another project you should add that project's reference to your web project's build path. if it is in same project check if it is in a source folder.

Comment: same project source folder

Answer (score -1):

Try to use <%@ page import="java_files.*" %>